# Nodejs crypto digest result

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, hash, cryptography

The `.digest('hex')` method gives a hex representation of the hash, but is there a way to print it in the same format as the linux hashes are stored?

In linux the password hashes are stored like this:

```
$6$xxx$E2AAPa0Ypl30EPsSEii5e00E5UtzS.4Wfd4Q3mEjhAFteMVrk1dGhfG8bPlo04/8YCrmcXWlm6nEiuPZdz5C9/
```

Comment: [this](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-passwd) might help